# Azure Self-hosted Windows agent hook

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

In Azure DevOps we have a Pipeline and Release created and working. In the release, we have the Azure Self-hosted Windows agent running and publishing to the off-site server without any issues.

Once the agent has completed deployment of the website, we would like to run a script on the Self-hosted server. *(example POST HOOK COMMAND > C:\srvscripts\azure-post-hook.ps1)*

Where can configure the agent to run a script once the website is published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can configure the agent to run a script once the website is published?

If you want to run a script once the website is published on the on the Self-hosted server, you could add a powershell task after the task your deployment the website:

[image]

Since you are running the script on the **Self-hosted server**, we could directly specify the path `C:\srvscripts\azure-post-hook.ps1` where the script is located in the scripts path option:

[image]